# Can we solve a matrix equation when the vectors are given and the matrix is variable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, quantum-mechanics, unitary-matrices

Usually, a matrix equation means that
$$
Ax = b
$$
when A and b are given and x is the variable we want to know.

However, when x and b are given and we want to know the value of the matrix, is it acheivable?

To provide context, I'm studying quantum computing and I tried to figure out if a certain state vector can be derived from $ |00...0 \rangle $ with unitary transformations. So you can assume $ A $ is unitary and $ b $ is $ |00...0 \rangle $.

Now I'm almost brute-forcing to solve this kind of equation, so even though there is no general algorithm for it, just giving some tips and tricks would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is unitary then $x$ and $b$ must have the same magnitude; otherwise it is impossible.

If $x$ and $b$ have the same magnitude, then yes there exist many unitary matrices that satisfy the equation. One such example is the reflection

$$A = I - 2 \frac{(x-b)(x-b)^*}{(x-b)^*(x-b)}$$
where the $*$ indicates conjugate transpose. You can check that $A$ us unitary by verifying $A^*=A$ and $A^* A = A^2 = I$.